# Cannot browse or open http sites using Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser

I have installed Firefox 18.1 in Windows XP SP3 and after installation I am not able to browse any http sites, I can only browse https sites.

I do not have any addons or plugins installed.

What could be the reason for this and how can I resolve this?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Update 1

Screen shot
[image]

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to browse a non-https site? Does it load forever, or display an error message, and if so which?

Comment: @MarcusChan I have added screen shot of my error page by adding in my question as Update 1

Comment: You did not say what network you are on - a simple router at home, or a corporate/organizational network with security, proxies etc.? Looks like it may be a proxy issue.

Comment: @JanSchejbal I am on corporate network and using proxy settings. In IE proxy setting is `Automatically Detect Settings` and FF I have ticked `Auto Detect Proxy Settings for this network.`

Comment: Your problem is incorrect proxy settings, or the proxy interfering with your connection. Try to configure the proxy manually, or try to select the "use system proxy settings" in Firefox.

Comment: @JanSchejbal I have tried `system proxy settings` and no luck. If I have incorrect proxy settings then how come I am able to browse https sites?

Comment: HTTPS often doesn't use the proxy, because the proxy can do very little to it anyways (HTTPS is encrypted). If you are allowed to use Firefox, kindly ask the admin over a cup of coffe or look at the proxy settings on some machine where it works. If you are not allowed to use Firefox, it is possible that the proxy is blocking you (although that would usually lead to a different error).

Comment: @JanSchejbal Thanks for the detailed explanation. On my PC, Internet Explorer works, however when I tried to put the same settings in Firefox, it doesn't work. Firefox was working fine on my PC before the upgrade, not sure what happened after the upgrade.

Comment: @Polppan - You will have to ask your network admin that question.